# Error during compilation - Extra parameters passed to parent construct

Tags: di, setup, compile

During deployment when i run setup:di:compile i got error in one of my block, Extra parameters passed to parent construct: $data
Guide me on this issue

File name:index.php
File location:app/code/one80solution/categoryfinder/block/categoryfinder/index.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 One80Solution . All rights reserved.
 */
namespace One80Solution\CategoryFinder\Block\CategoryFinder;
use One80Solution\CategoryFinder\Block\BaseBlock;
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
class Index extends BaseBlock
{
    protected $_categoryCollectionFactory;
    protected $_categoryHelper;
        
    public function __construct(
        \One80Solution\CategoryFinder\Block\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
        $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    
    public function getFirstLevelCategories(){
        $collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*'); 
        $collection->addIsActiveFilter();
        $collection->addLevelFilter(2);
        
        return $collection;
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at your construct

```
parent::__construct($context, $data);
```

Does it require **$data**?

If not, remove it

```
parent::__construct($context);
```

Comment: Thank you Error got fixed

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer when you can :) 
Glad you got it working